# Set nested fields in Golang with the Logrus?

Tags: go, logging

I'm using [`github.com/sirupsen/logrus`](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) to make a logger. This simplifies how fields are being initiated in the logger (straightforward from docs):

```
package main

import "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"

func main() {
    logFields := logrus.Fields{
        "details": logrus.Fields{
            "app_name":    "Some name",
            "app_version": "Some version",
        },
    }

    logger := logrus.New()
    logger.WithFields(logFields)
}
```

The library seems to allow to add fields with method `WithFields` only at top level (as in the last line).

But because my API has many steps, I need to add nested fields under `details` with every step (to accumulate log data), then output it all together in the end.

How can I add these fields?

Comment: The Logrus document mentioned that for nested fields you should use the third part formatters like this: [nested-logrus-formatter](http://nested-logrus-formatter)

Comment: @OmidTavakoli I looked into it. It doesn't really do key nesting into `entires`, which is the object inside the library. It's just another formatter.

Answer (score 2):

`logrus.Fields` is just `map[string]interface{}`, so you can nest all data in every steps into a struct like

```golang
type Details struct {
    Step1 string `json:"step1"`
    Step2 string `json:"step2"`
    Step3 string `json:"step3"`
}
```

and finally `logger.WithFields(logFields).Debugln("some debug info")`

Another method, you can create multiple variables to save data from every step, for example

```golang
var step1data = "step1"
var step2data = "step2"
```

and finally

```golang
logger.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
        "details": logrus.Fields{
            "step1": step1data,
            "step2": step2data,
        },
    }).Debugln("some debug info")`
```

Comment: Thanks! But be being a newbie, and going with the 1st choice, can you update your answer with a method that initiate `details`, and then a method that adds one step to it? Methods need to be called form other packages, and `details` object should persist.